# minitoc not showing up

Tags: input, thesis, minitoc

```
\documentclass[12pt, doublespacing]{ociamthesis}  % default square logo 
%\documentclass[12pt,beltcrest]{ociamthesis} % use old belt crest logo
%\documentclass[12pt,shieldcrest]{ociamthesis} % use older shield crest logo
\usepackage{xcolor}
%load any additional packages
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\usepackage{filecontents}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,wrapfig} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
%\usepackage{cite}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{tocbibind}


\begin{document}

%this baselineskip gives sufficient line spacing for an examiner to easily
%markup the thesis with comments
%\baselineskip=18pt plus1pt 
%\baselineskip=24pt plus1pt 
%\setstretch{2}
%\linespread{1.6}


%set the number of sectioning levels that get number and appear in the contents
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\dominitoc
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\newcommand\AAnotes[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\maketitle                  % create a title page from the preamble info
\include{dedication} % include a dedication.tex file
\pagenumbering{roman}
\include{acknowlegements}   % include an acknowledgements.tex file

\section*{Abstract}
\input{abstract.tex}          % include the abstract
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

\newpage
\section*{Publications}
\input{publications.tex}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Publications}

\newpage
\section*{List of Abbreviations}
\input{abbreviations.tex}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}


\tableofcontents 

\listoffigures              % generate and include a list of figures

\listoftables            

\clearpage
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\setstretch{2}
%now include the files of latex for each of the chapters etc
%\begin{doublespacing}

\input{chapter1.tex}
\minitoc

\input{chapter2.tex}

\input{chapter3.tex}

\input{chapter7.tex}

\input{chapter4.tex}

\input{chapter5.tex}

\input{chapter6.tex}

\input{conclusions.tex}

%\end{doublespacing}

%now enable appendix numbering format and include any appendices
\appendix
\include{appendix1}
\include{appendix2}

%next line adds the Bibliography to the contents page
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
%uncomment next line to change bibliography name to references
%\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\linespread{1.3}
\bibliography{refs}        %use a bibtex bibliography file refs.bib
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}  %use the plain bibliography style

\end{document}
```

I am not sure why the minitoc is not showing.

my chapter1.tex file starts with

```
\chapter{} \minitoc
text....
\section{}
etc...
```

I tried `\include` instead of `\input` but didn't see any difference. I need to use the ociamthesis class as it is tailored to my university requirements. I tried reading few threads about it and still can't locate what could be different and how can i tell if the `\dominitoc` is actually working?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: `\include{acknowlegements} ` has a typo. But help yourself by removing all non-relevant packages, try with book class etc...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Alan The most important thing is having `\dominitoc` *before* `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: Is there any news here?